# NSString to NSDate is giving the wrong day

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this piece of code:

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
df.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
df.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *todaysDate = @"31/12/2013";
NSDate* today = [df dateFromString:todaysDate];

NSLog(@"comparing todaysDate: %@ with today: %@",todaysDate,today);
```

When I check my console I see that todaysDate is 31/12/2013 and today is 2013-12-30 21:00:00 +0000  I do not understand why it goes 1 day into the past... can anyone help me out here? I'm trying to basically filter out some items in a dictionary based on date. Filtering part not included here as it was determined that the dateFromString is not doing its job.

Comment: Check in your device that Settings->General->Date& time-> Time zone and device that Settings->General->International->Region formats

Comment: Yes, it is issue with your time settings. The code is perfect when checked in online Objective C compiler

Comment: "31/12/2013" in your time zone is the same as "2013-12-30 21:00:00 +0000" (which reports the time in UTC). - This is asked and answered frequently, see above "possible duplicate" or google for "NSDate wrong".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's very probably because of your TimeZone. You seems to be GMT+3 or something like that. If you change your local Time Zone things should be ok.

You should use : `df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]:` instead of `localTimeZone`to always have the same results even in different time zones.

Comment: That's was it! thanks Zaphod

Comment: You're welcome! I live in a GMT+1 zone and I often see that kind of problems... ;o) And by the way, Happy New Year...

Comment: I'm adding this piece of code to all my apps in the future lol... Happy New Year to all :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the below to your NSDateFormatter.

```
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Answer (score -4):

When I program with dates I always use this code, I'm sorry but I can't help you with NSString to NSDate because I don't use that code myself

hire is solution to your problem:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
cout << (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-' 
     << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
     <<  now->tm_mday
     << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you know exact answer or little bit relevant to answer. Then only post your answer here. It's totally irrelevant. Do you know xcode tool ?

Comment: This is not an answer.